# jQuery remove class from parent on click

Tags: jquery, click, parent-child, addclass, removeclass

I have an element that once you click on it, it adds and removes a class with jQuery. When you click on a child element I want the classes to swap again.
I tried doing it with `.parent` but that doesn't seem to work..

This is the html:

```
<article class="block inactive">
  <span class="close"></span>
</article>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive'),
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('inactive');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

**EDIT**

Solution:

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent('.block').toggleClass('inactive active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The event is propagating when you click on the child element, triggering the click handler on the parent element (effectively undoing what the click handler on the child element has just done)

Comment: First part works when clicking the article, but when I click `.close` it doesn't switch the classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `.close` is a child of the `.block` the event is propagating back up and also triggering the handler oon the `.block`, which means that the classes are getting reverted straight away. You can use `.stopPropagation()` to stop this happening:

```js
$('.block').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive'),
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().addClass('inactive');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.inactive{ background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="block inactive">
    in the block
  <span class="close">in the close</span>
</article>
```

There are a number of other enhancements you can make to simplify your code, but they are tangential to the question, for completeness

1. chain your methods to save repeating yourself
2. consider if`toggleClass` is more appropriate than `addClass`/`removeClass`.

```js
$('.block').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.inactive{ background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="block inactive">
    in the block
  <span class="close">in the close</span>
</article>
```